# Function that returns sum between two numbers

Tags: python

I am currently in my first programming class and have to create a function that returns the sum of two numbers. I am receiving an error when running the following code. It appears to be with my print statement, but there could be other things I am missing. I would like to understand so any input is greatly appreciated!

```
first_number = input("Enter first number:  ")
second_number = input("Enter second number:  ")

def sum_between(first_number, second_number):

    while first_number <= second_number:
        sum_between_numbers = range(first_number, (second_number +(str(1)))
        print(sum_between_numbers)
```

Comment: Please provide the error message. The first thing I see here as a problem is that `while first_number <= second_number` is an infinite loop if you enter it. Along with that `range` isn't doing what you think it does.

Comment: 1) When you don't know what function does, google it. Here you don't know what `range` and, I think, `str` do. 2) Provide the full error.

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns the sum of two numbers:

```
def sum(first, second):
    return first + second
```

A function that returns the sum of *all the numbers between those two numbers, inclusive*:

```
def sum_between(first, second):
    nums_between = range(first, second+1)  # Generates a list [first, first+1, first+2, ..., second]
    sum_between = 0  # initialize the sum between as 0
    for num in nums_between:  # count through every number from first to second...
        sum_between += num    # ...and add them together
    return sum_between   # return the sum of all of that
```

A more pythonic way to do it would be to use the built-in function `sum()`, which takes any iterable and returns the sum of all the items inside:

```
def sum_between(first, second):
    nums_between = range(first, second + 1)
    return sum(nums_between)
```

Then, you just need to call your code:

```
first_number = int(input("Enter first number: "))  # the input() function returns a string; we need to typecast it to an integer first
second_number = int(input("Enter second number: "))
...
print(sum_between(first_number, second_number))
```

---

Keep in mind that python is not javascript. Python cares what type two things are, and if you try to add an `int` and a `str` together you're probably going to get an error. Integer addition works like this:

```
1 + 2 == 3
```

String addition (called "concatenation") works like this:

```
'1' + '2' == '12'
```

This is part of the problem you were running into in your code - I'll leave it to you to investigate where it came into play. Good learning exercise.

Comment: Note: there is a closed form for summing up sequential values: `(first+second)*(second-first+1)//2`